# Application VLOOKUP no value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am inputting data based on a VLOOKUP code but keep getting an error.

```
    For Each Cell In Rng
    Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cell, Table2, 1, False)

    Next
```

I want Column C to either post the VLOOKUP value or return a message 'Returned Item Not Scanned'. I was using a error handler to do this however I keep getting an error when this runs.

```
          'MyErrorHandler:
           ' If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            '     Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Returned Item Not Scanned"
           ' ElseIf Err.Number = 13 Then
           ' MsgBox "Incorrect Exceptions Data."
           ' Else
           '
            ' End If
```

Error is stating 'Unable to get VLookup Property of the WorksheetFunction Class.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Forgot to add if I do this manually the formula is this - =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,'311A Data'!A:A,1,FALSE),"Returned Item Not Scanned")

Comment: Firstly, what is `Table1`? - secondly you're using the wrong formula. You want a `=MATCH()` for this, not a `=VLOOKUP()`

Comment: Table 1 is the range '311A Data'!A:A

Comment: I'll try the Match code can this be input as a code instead of inputting the formula?

Comment: Yes, it's part of the `WorksheetFunction` class just like your existing code.

Comment: @Alan Treanor  try the code in my answer below, let me know if this is what you meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the piece of code below, I am using `Application.VLookup` in order to trap the errors.

(When trapping the `VLookup` errors in this method, you are not getting 1004 for `Err.Number`)

```
Option Explicit

Sub VLookup_with_ErrHandling()

Dim Cell                As Range
Dim Rng                 As Range
Dim Table2              As Range

' modify "Table2" range to your needs
Set Table2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C20")

' modify "Rng" range to your needs
Set Rng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10")

For Each Cell In Rng
    If Not IsError(Application.VLookup(Cell, Table2, 1, False)) Then
        Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Application.VLookup(Cell, Table2, 1, False)
    Else
        Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Returned Item Not Scanned"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```